# NSUserDefaults check if value exist for key

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have `UICollectionView` contains: `UIlabel` and `UIButton` (text in labels comes from API) 
[image]

when I press `UIButton` text from `UIlabel`  and CostLbl stored in UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car")

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image!, 1.0) as NSData? 
let newValues = ["name": self.nameLbl.text ?? "", "price": self.costLbl.text ?? "", "image": imageData]

var mArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car") as? [[String: Any]]
 maAr?.append(newValues)
```

Question : when `UIButton` is press need to check  if text from `UIlabel` is in array(forKey: "car") , if not - can to stored for key,, and if text already in array(forKey: "car") cant add to array

I wrote as  vadian suggested

```
var maAr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car") as? [[String: Any]] ?? [] 
if !maAr.contains(where: newValues) { 
maAr.append(newValues) 
def.set(maAr, forKey: "car") 
}
```

but catch error to `(where: newValues)` -

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '([String : Any]) throws -> Bool'
```

How can this be changed?

Comment: You have a wrong question, you talking about array that is `[String]`, but saving your value in UserDefaults as `[[String:Any]]`. Please correct your question and ask again.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. I suggested `[[String:String]]` rather than `[[String:Any]]`.

Comment: Нes, but how can I do it [[String:Any]] ?   because I want to add in `newValues ` new key-value like 
    `let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image!, 1.0) as NSData?
        let newValues = ["name": self.nameLbl.text ?? "", "price": self.costLbl.text ?? "", "image": imageData]`

Comment: newValues  as `[String : Any]`

Comment: @vadian , do You know how it can be done?

Comment: You can use an unspecified array but then you have to cast and compare each value separately. Simply `contains` does not work with `Any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declare the dictionary as `[String:String]` in this case there is no type cast and no annotation.

```
let newValues = ["name": nameLbl.text ?? "", "price": costLbl.text ?? ""]
```

Read the array, check if the array contains the value, if NO append the item and save the array back, if YES do nothing

```
var carArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car") as? [[String: String]] ?? []
if !carArray.contains(newValues) {
   carArray.append(newValues)
   UserDefaults.standard.set(carArray, forKey: "car")
}
```

Comment: Add .      `var maAr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car") as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
        if !maAr.contains(where: newValues) {
            maAr.append(newValues)
            def.set(maAr, forKey: "car")
        }` . but have error  in `(where: newValues)`  - `Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '([String : Any]) throws -> Bool'`

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to use more specific types. `Any` is bad as always.

Comment: But Im need `[String : Any]`, because price is Int, how can I convert?

Comment: `costLbl.text` implies it's `String`